# In Ble, Can I transfer a data package larger than MTU?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

Suppose I want to transfer some data (100 bytes) by ble and MTU is 50 bytes, can I make a 100 bytes package and just send out one time？

In my test，the data was truncated. So does it means we have to subpackage the data by our app manually and send them out one by one and repackage them manually in the other side?

Does android have any API to enable subpackage and repackage automatically？

```
        gatt.requestMtu(100);
```

```
        @Override
        public void onMtuChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, int mtu, int status) {
            super.onMtuChanged(gatt, mtu, status);
            //// here the mtu is 50
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

When developing a BLE application on Android or other high-level operating systems, you can practically ignore the MTU. Best to leave it up to the system to negotiate the configuration.

However that doesnt mean you can just send data of arbitrary length. With BLE, data is transferred from/to bluetooth service characteristics, and these have a maximum length which you cannot exceed, as well as permissions and access-control flags.

To find your maximum packet length, get the size of the characteristic you writing into. The developer of this characteristic should ideally make sure that the characteristics length is equal to or a multiple of the device's MTU.

The only exception to this is if your characteristic is used for notifications (as opposed to read or write). In this case, the maximum length of the characteristic is equal to the device's MTU.

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer@markus-nm.  1,  "get the size of the characteristic you writing into", but how? it seems that no api can do this.  2,  if the characteristic has both write and notify function,  what's the maximum length of this characteristic? 3, since the MTU may be changed by gatt.requestMtu, so how to "make sure that the characteristics length is equal to or a multiple of the device's MTU" ?

Comment: 1. There must be an API to get the characteristic size. Anyway the size should be static, so you could use any other app to check the length (search nrf in your app-store), or maybe there's a datasheet available for the device you are connecting to.
2. If it can be used for regular write-requests, it can be of any length. The notifications however will be only as long as the MTU size.
3. It sounds like you have no access to the peripheral device you are connecting to. You would have to change the firmware to change the size of the characteristics.